# Turning on a fan through a relay power-cycles a Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: relay, fan, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to control a fan [1](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0C2H6KXQS?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1) using a Raspberry Pi Pico and a relay [2](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B09LS7S1H7?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details).

The relay is connected to the Pico on pin 19 (GP14) for signal, to GND, and to 3V3.

The Pico is powered and controlled through USB on a laptop running on battery.

Connections between Pico and relay are wires soldered to the through-holes of the Pico and clamped into the clamps of the relay.
Connections between power, relay, and fan are wires clamped to the relay using its clamp connectors and to the fan using wago clamps.

Setting GP14 to 'high' power-cycles the Pico most of the time.
Sometimes, the Pico survives turning the fan on and off once, but then it dies when GP14 is set to 'high' the second time.

This only happens when the fan has power, and only when it is the fan I'm powering.
When the fan does not have power, or when I connect a light bulb (42W) instead of the fan, I can go back between 'high' and 'low' on GP14 as often as I like.

The fan isn't obviously broken either: when I connect it straight to mains, it will spin up without problems.

What could provoke this behavior and how can I prevent it?

*Edited: added schematic, implementation details.*

[image: schematic; the MC is really a raspberry pi pico, the relay is the relay linked, the motor is really a fan]

Comment: Please post a schematic and layout. Most probably due to (poor) layout and lack of decoupling capacitors.

Comment: Have you powered all of the Pico, Relay and Fan from the Laptop's USB? Try adding a large-ish capacitor near the Pico and Relay's coil power input. A schematic would certainly help, along with clarity about how this is implemented (presumably wires, not a PCB?)

Comment: Done. Sorry for the quality: I have very little experience drawing schematics and none using fritzing; also, I didn't find the Pico or the exact relay I'm using in fritzing.  I hope the drawing is still useful.

Comment: @Attie I can't power the fan from USB, because it takes 220V input, but I have powered the Pico and relay from USB.  I have also tried powering the Pico and relay or only the relay from a separate 5V power supply.  The results were the same.